# Correct use of AND OR (|| &&) with two string values

Tags: php

I could not find the answer to this anywhere, and it's a newbee mistake. Can someone help me with this statement:

```
<?php 
if ($db_ownrPlan == 'sell in a year or so' || 'get some info only no plans made yet'){
    echo "$TYmessage";
} elseif ($db_ownrPlan == 'sell soon' || 'sell in 3 to 6 months' || 'looking to buy this property'){
    echo "$TYmessage1";
} else {
    echo "$TYmessage2";
} 
?>
```

Comment: `$variable == 'value'` is a comparison which returns a `boolean` value (`true` or `false`). `'get some info only no plans made yet'` is a string and won't return a **boolean value**. You have to make a comparison again: `if ($db_ownrPlan == 'sell in a year or so' || $db_ownrPlan == 'get some info only no plans made yet')`. The `&&` and  `||` operators combine logical (boolean) values to return another boolean value.

Comment: You couldn't find an answer anywhere? Really? Come on, the PHP documentation itself teaches you how to write conditional statements. What prevented you from reading through it?

Comment: @AlejandroIván: Strings can convert to booleans just fine. It's just not what you want to happen here (or, frankly, anywhere).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit you're right. I just "removed" some data for him/her to understand ;P

Comment: @AlejandroIván: You removed some data from him to understand, then added some incorrect data for him to be misinformed. :(

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit ouch, touchè! Sorry :)

Comment: @AlejandroIván: Teeheehee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you want to do:

```
<?php 
if ($db_ownrPlan == 'sell in a year or so' || $db_ownrPlan == 'get some info only no plans made yet'){
    echo "$TYmessage";
} elseif ($db_ownrPlan == 'sell soon' || $db_ownrPlan == 'sell in 3 to 6 months' || $db_ownrPlan == 'looking to buy this property'){
    echo "$TYmessage1";
} else {
    echo "$TYmessage2";
} 
?>
```

In PHP, and most other programming languages with similar syntax, you would compare variables like this:

```
VAR == value OR VAR == otherValue
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (in_array($db_ownrPlan, 
   array('sell in a year or so', 'get some info only no plans made yet')))
```

and so on for compact form (did not check for the speed)...

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is:

```
($db_ownrPlan == 'sell in a year or so' || $db_ownrPlan =='get some info only no plans made yet')
```

Otherwise the second condition is merely the string but not a comparison.